# Is blush-on the same thing as a blusher?

Tags: word-meaning, synonyms

In the movie "Taxi Driver" by Martin Scorsese There is a scene in which one of the cab drivers is telling a story in which he uses the word blush-on. Is this the same thing as blusher or rouge? Can't find this word in any dictionary.

TFD def for blusher
2. a cosmetic similar to rouge, used to add color to the cheeks.

Comment: I think we need to have more context. Can you quote the sentances surrounding the "blush-on"?

Comment: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/blush-on = blusher  TFD also has a redirect for blush-on to blusher.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly the same thing. [I am a woman and use it. The old name is blush-on, the newer name for it is blusher.]

Comment: James, Does it mean that if you are redirected, the words that you are seeing, are always the definitions pertinent to your search?